# Unable connect to android phone using bluetooth

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, android, bluetooth

How do I connect my laptop to my HTC Wildfire through bluetooth?
The laptop is running xubuntu 11.10, and I have updated Blueman to version 1.23 through their launchpad PPA.

The phone is running android version 2.2.1.

I can 'pair' and 'trust' the phone, but I can neither 'send files to device...' nor 'browse files on device...'

I am able to connect and browse the phone using my netbook running xubuntu 10.04 and blueman version 1.21.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,